# Im not sure how to get the data from my text field

Tags: java, swing, awt, review

I want to get the data from my textfield and set it to int h. and have that change the size of the rectangle im drawing, but im not sure how to go get the data from the textfield, I tired using e.getsource in actionperfomred but it cannot find my textfield.    My code is below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

/**
 * This class demonstrates how to load an Image from an external file
 */
public class test extends Component {

    int x=77, y=441, w=23, h=10;

    BufferedImage img =
  new BufferedImage(100, 50,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);    
   // BufferedImage img;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
           // g.fillRect(10,10,10,10);
    }

    public test() {
       try {
           img = ImageIO.read(new File("sales-goal.png"));
       } catch (IOException e) {}


       Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
       Color myColor = Color.decode("#32004b");
       g.setColor(myColor);
       g.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
                //77,441,23,10
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (img == null) {
             return new Dimension(100,100);
        } else {
           //return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
            return new Dimension(300,600);
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Load Image Sample");
        JTextField textField=new JTextField();
        f.add(textField);
        textField.setBounds(10,10,40,30);
        textField.setVisible(true);

        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

        f.add(new test());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               // if (e.getSource() == textField) {}

    }
}
```

Comment: this is a good question for: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Don't mix Swing (`JFrame`) with AWT (`Component`) components.  The `test` class should extend `JPanel` (and should properly be capitalized as `Test`).  The it would need to override `paintComponent()` rather than `paint()`.

Comment: That being done, Im still not sure how to get the data in main through actionperformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `textField` is local to `main`. If you want to access it from `actionPerformed`, you'll need to change it to an instance variable.

Comment: how do I make it an instance variable and how would i then added it to the j frame, to the frame since that is also in main.  should I move everything in main?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. I agree with @jpm. You need to declare it as an instance variable.
Do the following:-

```
  public class test extends Component {
       //Declare the variable here.
       private static JTextField textfield;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       //Whenever you use the textfield use like this. Remove the keyword 'JTextField'.
       textfield = new JTextField();
  }
  }
```

Comment: I did that and added this to my actionperformed but im not getting the data                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        Graphics g= getGraphics();
        
               if (e.getSource() == textField) {
                   entry= Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                   g.drawString("Test",50,50);
                   
                   entry=h;
                   
                }

Comment: I can't understand what you are saying. Explain Briefly.

Comment: Check whether you have used the same Variable names: private JTextField textField; and textField = new JTextField();

Comment: I declared them like you said, but I didnt make them private  JTextField textField;
JFrame f=new JFrame();                                                              using the same names I use in my main and my actionperformed, Where would I add the actionlistner to the textfield, I think that is why im not getting anything when i enter an int in the texfield in actionperformed I put if (e.getSource() == textField) {
              entry=Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());                        or is it that its not reloading or repainting after