# Page is not refreshing or not getting the input from my text field

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Im not sure how to get the data from my text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145493/im-not-sure-how-to-get-the-data-from-my-text-field)

I am entering a number into a text field and using that input to change an int which will change the size of a rectangle,  Im not sure if something is wrong, where im not getting that data from that textfield or the page is just not reloading after it gets that data.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;


public class Test extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    JTextField textField;
    JFrame f=new JFrame();
    int x=77, y=441, w=23, h=10, entry;
    BufferedImage img=null;

   // BufferedImage img;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage img =new BufferedImage(100, 50,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 
        //textField = new JTextField();
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Load Image Sample");
        JTextField textField=new JTextField();
        f.add(textField);
        textField.setBounds(10,10,40,30);
        textField.setVisible(true);

        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

        f.add(new Test());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

        Graphics2D i = img.createGraphics();
       Color myColor = Color.decode("#32004b");
       i.setColor(myColor);
       i.fillRect(x,y,w,h);

           // g.fillRect(10,10,10,10);
    }

    public Test() {

       try {
           img = ImageIO.read(new File("sales-goal.png"));
       } catch (IOException e) {}


                //77,441,23,10
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (img == null) {
             return new Dimension(100,100);
        } else {
           //return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
            return new Dimension(300,600);
       }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Graphics g= getGraphics();
        textField.addActionListener(this);

               if (e.getSource() == textField) {
                   entry= Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                   g.drawString("Test",50,50);

                   entry=h;

                }         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing

```
JTextField textField=new JTextField();
```

in the main method which is creating a new local variable but your global `JTextField textField;` is never assigned. In your actionPerformed, you are using the global `textField` which is never initialized.

Comment: They also do not appear to be assigning the action listener in the correct place. but your point is also definitely valid.

Comment: how do I use my global textField in main

Comment: You are putting all the initialization in the static main and that's why you can't access the global(instance) variables. I will suggest you to extends JFrame class separately so you can use the instance variables.

Comment: ive tried taking all of that out of the main and putting them elsewhere (public void init) and just leaving the new JFrame in the main but it wasn't adding the text field to the frame

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable as

```
     private static JTextField textField;
```

Remove 'JTextField' and use it as

```
     textField = new JTextField();
```

in your main method

Answer (score 0):

I would replace this line in your main method:

```
JTextField textField=new JTextField();
```

With these:

```
textField=new JTextField();
textField.addActionListener(this);
```

Then I would remove this line from your `actionPerformed` method:

```
textField.addActionListener(this);
```

Comment: Ive tried that but It wont let me reference a non static vaiable text field form a static context

Comment: Then make it static. Honestly I wouldnt put my main method inside the JPanel in the first place which would eliminate a lot of this confusion, but you could always declare the variable as static at the beginning of your program. Just replace `JTextField textField;` with `static JTextField textField;`

Comment: I would also recommend some Swing tutorials. My first swing GUIs were dreadful and its taken me ages to get to a point where I am confident in my designs. It may sound tedious, but the only way to learn is by doing it, so tutorials are a big help. But if you dont plan on doing much GUI development in the future then you can get by with just a hackish solution (as long as it works right).